# How to install Hudson on windows server 2008?

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008, hudson

I'm calm... Everyone loves windows...

1,2,3,4,5...10

Ok

---

How to install [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) on windows 2008?

More specifically - what exactly is 'Windows filtering platform' thingy and how to kick it so it would allow Hudson pass through?

This is what i get in event log when i hit `java -jar hudson.war` and try to open web page:

> The Windows Filtering Platform has blocked a bind to a local port.
>
> Application Information:
>       Process ID:     2896
>       Application Name:   \device\harddiskvolume1\windows\system32\java.exe
>
> Network Information:
>       Source Address:     ::
>       Source Port:        5353
>       Protocol:       17
>
> Filter Information:
>       Filter Run-Time ID: 0
>       Layer Name:     Resource Assignment
>       Layer Run-Time ID:  38

Temporary disabled firewall through control panel - nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfp/thread/774026e6-a771-418a-b531-22183ef399f8

The problem you're having is that, while you turned off the firewall, the rules are still affecting it. Try disabling MPSSvc and running it again. Or try:

```
Netsh.exe AdvFirewall Set CurrentProfile State Off
```

Obviously, be very careful if this is a production environment.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kind of speculating here, but maybe try running it in Tomcat?  I'd hope the Tomcat team put the work into their installer/Windows Service to have it handle port binding without too much headache...

Answer (score 1):

We've been running Hudson in Apache Tomcat on Windows Servers for almost two years now without incident.  I never even tried to run it through IIS (assuming that's what you're using).  Just run the Windows installer for [Tomcat 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) (7.0 may not yet be supported) and then drop hudson.war in the Tomcat webapps directory.  Tomcat will automatically extract the .war contents and start up the application.  You may also want to get into the Hudson configuration files and set the value of the HUDSON_HOME directory if you don't want it to use the default.